# Looking for plone howto combobox multiselect - take me from theory to practical

Tags: combobox, plone, multi-select

Not being a programmer, I am finding a huge gap of understanding in 
having Products.AddRemoveWidget
   and collective.js.ui.multiselect
successfully in buildout.cfg /Addon Product and then realising that I can't see it in Add Item like page, event, help center and then wanting to actually employ the displayed data in the combobox / listbox

In my case, as a travel agent, I want to build a mult-select logical walk through based on 30 years of being a travel consultant. Thinking of the expression "Like this / Do that"

"Cascading widgets" - Looking for Novice / Intermediate / Experienced entry points

```
COUNTRY
  |
  |         STATE             Tourism Region   Local Council     Local Town
Australia - South Australia - Barossa Valley - Barossa Council - Nuriootpa - local item
  |                                                                          This would
  |                                                                          be more
  |                                                                          specific
```

The meta-search would dictate where the entry level is, and the start navigation point.

I know what I'd like, but must learn to crawl before anything else.

Does anyone have a tutorial / how-to to get me from theory to practical.

With thanks
Michael Wunderlich

Comment: Products.AddRemoveWidget is meant for programmers.

I think I understand what you're looking for but I don't think it can be done without programming knowledge. Unless there is a product I'm unaware of...

Comment: I think you need to be more clear about what you want. Are you talking about a search form that leads you to a list of content items? like what eea.facetednavigtion gives you? Or are you talking about a form that results in an email query being sent? Or is this about fields on your content types which are classifications of your content?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Now I'd recommend [Plomino](http://plomino.net/) as a solution for complex forms. It has a hidewhen concept to create dynamic forms and it doesn't require much programming.

You still haven't clarified what it is you want, so instead I'll list two approaches which might help you.

Faceted Navigation using [eea.facetednagivation](http://plone.org/products/eea.facetednavigation)

Here you create items and then classify them, then using this plugin you can create a very custom listing form which allows your users to select different criteria narrow down the set of results. The methods for classification depend on your usecase but you can use

- normal plone pages and the default tag field
- a plugin like collective.facets to add addition tag fields
- a custom content type to have full control over the fields. e.g. using dexterity

Alternatively, what you might be meaning is a kind of multipage form or "wizrard". The easiest way to achieve this is using PloneFormGen plugin using this [method](http://plone.org/products/ploneformgen/documentation/how-to/create-a-multi-page-form). This method can create [reasonably sophisticated forms such as this form we produced for a client](http://www.cmc.qld.gov.au/topics/misconduct/online-complaint-form/intro_form). (note we also used a plugin called [collective.stepypfg](http://svn.plone.org/svn/collective/collective.stepypfg/trunk/collective/stepypfg/) to achieve the 2nd wizard in that form)